# Order of containers in docker ps

Tags: shell, docker, awk, ps

I believe `docker ps` lists the containers in a chronological order of their creation (newest to oldest).

Can someone please confirm this? I’m writing a library and I need to pick the latest container. I am currently doing that by listing the container ids and picking the first one.

`docker ps -a -f --format '{{.ID}} | awk 'NR==1'`

Is this guaranteed to pick up the latest container? If not, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: This is a good question to ask: If something isn't listed in the documentation, it's an implementation detail and can change at any time without notice. Writing tools that integrate with other software, you should depend only on documented guarantees, not on mere observations of current behavior -- because if something isn't documented and it changes in the future, it isn't even a bug, just a change from one unspecified behavior to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a firm guarantee of order, use the `CreatedAt` timestamp to sort.

```
docker ps -a --format '{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.ID}}' | awk -F $'\t' '
  NR==1 { earliest = $1; result = $2; next; }
  $1 < earliest { earliest = $1; result = $2; }
  END { print result; }
'
```

...provides a firm guarantee of sort by creation time. (The `CreatedAt` field is a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` timestamp, so ASCII sort order works).

Comment: Since I want the latest, it should be '>'.

Comment: Can we use `sort`? ```docker ps -a --format '{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.ID}}'  | sort -k1 -r | awk 'NR==1 {print $5}'```

Comment: `sort` works fine; it's just extra overhead vs putting the work into awk (and needing to actually order the whole list, vs only finding the first or last element -- being an O(n log n) operation vs an O(n) one).

Comment: BTW, even if you *are* going the `sort | awk` route, make it `awk -F$'\t' '{print $2}'`; that way you don't care how many fields the current locale's date format splits into.

Comment: Got it, I guess I'll go the `awk` way since it's O(n). `sort` just looked more succinct.